# How can I reload data from chartjs after JSON file was modified in a HTTP POST

Tags: php, json, ajax, chart.js

My web page wants to display some data from a database in a chart. I'm using chartjs for drawing the chart. A php script is used to generate a json file which will be used to draw the chart.

I want to implement a filter which will select some specific data in agreement with user input. The input will be passed into the php script using HTTP Post. The json file created after is ok, but I don't know how to update the chart based on new json file.

```
<script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){  
           $('#filter').click(function(){  
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
                if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
                {                       
                      $.post("data.php", {
                      from_date: from_date
                      }, function(data,status) {
                      $("data").html(data);
                      });    
                }  

                else  
                {  
                     alert("Please Select Date");  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 </script>
```

The PHP script looks like:

```
if(isset($_POST["from_date"]))
{
$from = $_POST["from_date"];
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Temperature 
                    WHERE Temperature > '".$from."'
                ");
}
else
{
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Temperature 
                ");
}
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
print json_encode($data);
```

And the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var timestamp = [];
      var temperature  = [];
      var humidity = [];
      var pressure = [];

      for(var i in data) {
        timestamp.push(data[i].TimeStp);
        temperature.push(data[i].Temperature);
        humidity.push(data[i].Humidity);
        pressure.push(data[i].Pressure);
      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: timestamp,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'temperature',
            yAxisID: 'temperature',
            borderColor: 'rgba(120, 20, 60, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 20, 60, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220, 20, 60, 1)',
            data: temperature
          },
          {
            label: 'humidity',
            yAxisID: 'humidity',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 20, 60, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 20, 60, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255, 20, 60, 1)',
            data: humidity,
          }
        ]
      };



      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var barGraph1 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata,
        options: {
          showLines: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes:[{
               scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'TimeStamp'
                    }

            }],
            yAxes: [{
                id: 'temperature',
                position:'left',
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Temperature[C]'
                    },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:false
                }

              },

              {
                id: 'humidity',
                position:'right',
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Humidity[%]'
                    },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:false
                }
              }]
        }
      }
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

The json file is generated fine in HTTP POST, but I don't know how to redraw the chart based on that filter.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I've never used `chart.js` but a quick look on Google suggests that `chart.update();` might be the way to update it - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that will accept data. Just pass the data that you get from POST request and `chart.update()` will do the magic. Make sure to pass the chart reference in `chart` variable.

```
    function addData(chart, label, data) {
        chart.data.labels.push(label);
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(data);
        });
        chart.update();
    }
```